# Why does the MapBox-GL-JS map not pan or scroll when viewing the website on an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mapbox-gl-js

I have created a website that displays a map using the MapBox-GL-JS API. The map displays fine on desktop, but when I view the website on my iPhone, I am unable to move the map at all: it doesn't pan or scroll based on my tap gestures (however, the zoom buttons on the map still work). What could be the cause behind this, and what piece of code can I add to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried an example from [Mapbox example page](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/)?

Comment: Have you worked this out? Having the same issue example ->
http://output.jsbin.com/macoruj

Answer (score 1):

Is your map div fixed?  I'm having the same issue. For some reason it doesn't play well in a FIXED container.  Non-fixed works fine.

Comment: Yep, the same thing here. In my case it sticks after rotation of the map, before works fine.